# Editing in Visual Studio causes browser to go haywire with hundreds of requests per second

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, slick.js

This makes no sense. Visual Studio is causing my browser to spew hundreds of requests per seconds continually.

I am trying to add some click-tracking attributes to some elements on my page using razor and jQuery. Here's a sample:

```
$('.carousel').slick();
$('.carousel').$el.find('button.slick-next').attr("data-tracking-info", {"Description":"Next"});
```

This adds a bit of tracking code to my slick carousel object.

So:

- I am viewing my site in a separate browser window, not through VS.
- I make a minor change in my code, and save it.
- Then I go to my browser and refresh.
- I click on the next control and my browser starts sending this request (visible in Chrome>DevelopTools>Network-tab as well as fiddler) about a hundred times a second, forever:
  http://localhost:38038/300f23dee8...5a4c12/arterySignalR/send?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd...wbgIkKsovA%3D%3D&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fstore.dev.kobobooks.com%2F&browserName=Chrome&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F42.0.2311.135+Safari%2F537.36
- If I close down VS, the requests immediately stop, and do not (usually) resume unless I click on the button again.
- I notice when I restart VS, I get this, which cotnains a similar 'longpolling' reference: http://localhost:38830/21915...c9363c/arterySignalR/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd...ADO3vV2mQEFg3g8sol3ulDxIYL2PQ%3D%3D&messageId=d-54095821-B%2C0%7CC%2C1D07%7CD%2C0&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fstore.dev.kobobooks.com%2F&browserName=Chrome&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F42.0.2311.135+Safari%2F537.36&tid=3&_=1431005091245
- I can manage to do this even in incognito mode.

OK, maaaaaaybe this is related to my click-tracking code, but I'm really more interested in the triggering by Visual Studio. And more to-the-point, how I can defeat it. (I don't want to simply filter it out of what's being displayed.) As it is, I've got to shut down VS and relaunch it every time I make even the most minor of changes.

What's happening here?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't being caused by the [Browser Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) feature?  It's possible to disable those sorts of requests.

Comment: Ah. That seems to be the ticket. Thanks! (How can I flag your comment as the answer?)

Comment: You can't flag comments as answers, but I went ahead and posted my comment as an actual answer.  Glad to be of some help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Fiddler (or whatever) and you're seeing a gazillion requests being made while running, this could be being caused by the [Browser Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) feature of Visual Studio.  Browser Link can be toggled on/off by opening up the dropdown next to the Browser Link icon and unchecking `Enable Browser Link`.

The icon looks like this:

[image]